# Check channel permissions (owner) defaultrole before going further

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Well what i want is that every time when the owner does this command   tests!update that it first check if the channel named test has view only for @everyone before it goes further.. how can i achieve that ?

this is how i create the channel right now,

```
 init: (msg) => {
    if (!msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      return sendEmbed(msg, 'You need to have the administrator permission to do this.')
    }
    

    //checks if channel excist some=exist
      if (msg.guild.channels.some(r => r.name === "test")) {
        //sendEmbed(msg, 'you already have a channel called test.')
        } else {
        msg.guild.createChannel('test', {
  type: 'channel',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: msg.guild.defaultRole.id, // @everyone role
      allow: ['READ_MESSAGES']
    }
    
  ]
});
sendEmbed(msg, '#test created.')
  }
    
    const channel = client.guilds.get(msg.guild.id).channels.find(r => r.name === "test");

    if (channel) {
      sql.run('UPDATE settings SET partner = ? WHERE guildid = ?', [channel.id, msg.guild.id])
      sendEmbed(msg, 'Success!')
    } else {
      sendEmbed(msg, 'please re-run this command to finalize')
    }
  },
```

And here is the test!update

```
  update: (msg) => {

 i really dont know what to put here to check first the channel permissions before executing..
 
},
```

SOLUTION
Thanks MakeHellTal, this worked for me:

```
const channel = client.guilds.get(msg.guild.id).channels.find(r => r.name === "test");
             let everyone = msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone');
              let perms = channel.permissionsFor(everyone).serialize();
              if (perms.VIEW_CHANNEL && perms.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY && !perms.SEND_MESSAGES) {
                  
              }else{ 
            console.log("not working")
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextChannel#permissionsFor()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor)

```js
    let everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === '@everyone');
    let perms = channel.permissionsFor(everyone).serialize();
```

This finds @everyone and gets its perms, in an object.

[image: This is how the object will look.]

This is how the object will look. Then just use ifs to check each of these perms, and you're good to go!

If you want to check if a channel is read only for everyone, I'd use

```js
if (perms.VIEW_CHANNEL && perms.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY && !perms.SEND_MESSAGES) {
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: @MakeHellTall, thanks but that is not what i'm searching. i want that the bot checks if a CHANNEL has permission to read for EVERYONE. so it forces my script only to work if the channel had read only permission for everyone.  thanks

Comment: This is what this does; it checks the permissions @everyone has for a channel (message.channel in my case). Then you could check if `perms.VIEW_CHANNEL && perms.READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY && !(perms.SEND_MESSAGES)` to check if it's read only.

Comment: thx forthe reply, i did try what u said but it doesn't work for me. check my code i added the bit what i did try at last of the code. regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you wanted to check whether the user has the permission to modify channels. If yes:

```
if (msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: thx for info, no i want to check if a channel has (everyone) read-only permission before go further with the script.